# "to which" to "where" - the average age to which

Tags: relative-adverbs

Can I change "to which" to "where" in the sentence below?

> The practice of medicine has meant the average age to which people in all nations may expect to live is higher than it has been in recorded history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, age is not a location, and "to" serves an essential role.

Answer (score 0):

"To which" is correct, and while you could probably substitute "where" without comment, it doesn't quite fit.

However the entire sentence is confusing and poorly written.  When you run into situations where you have a choice between two awkward phrases, you should consider whether there is a better way to say what you mean. For example, "the average age to which people may expect to live" is called the "the average life expectancy".

Here's one way I would write it:

> With the help of modern medical practice, throughout the world the average life expectancy is higher than at any other time in recorded history.